# Django & VSCode: can't create super user

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

I don't know why but I can't run any comands in the vSCode Terminal.
For example, when I try `python manage.py createsuperuser` I get an error that can't find Python. So I do `py manage.py createsuperuser` and then I get a syntax error saying that manage.py doesn't exist or something like that.

Anyone know why this is and how I could fix it?

UPDATE:
I currently have the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\XXXXX\argon-dashboard-django\manage.py", line 13, in main
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\XXXXX\argon-dashboard-django\manage.py", line 23, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\XXXXX\argon-dashboard-django\manage.py", line 15, in main
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

Here's my manage.py

```
import os
import sys


def main():
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'core.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

So there seems to be an import error somewhere. And I tried it with my venv activated:

```
(env) C:\Users\valen\OneDrive\Bureau\DOCARET\Autres\argon-dashboard-django>py manage.py createsuperuser
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\valen\OneDrive\Bureau\DOCARET\Autres\argon-dashboard-django\manage.py", line 13, in main
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\valen\OneDrive\Bureau\DOCARET\Autres\argon-dashboard-django\manage.py", line 23, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\valen\OneDrive\Bureau\DOCARET\Autres\argon-dashboard-django\manage.py", line 15, in main
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

Comment: Do you have a venv for the project and did you activate it?

Comment: "_manage.py doesn't exist_", do you run the command from the _correct_ directory?(`cd` to your project directory before running)

Comment: I just try and use it from the terminal, I've done nothing else. the exact error I get is:
```manage.py createsuperuser
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    manage.py createsuperuser
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax```
With the arrow pointing at the createsuperuser first letter

Comment: Ok, I tried ./manage.py createsuperuser in the powershell terminal and it just opened the file manage.py nothing else

Comment: have you activated your venv?

Comment: I have a working web app and all so I guess it is activated. @MojixCoder

Comment: You need to activate it in your vscode terminal, if you can run your project through your vscode terminal then it is activated, if not then it's not active. notice if you are running your project in another terminal you need to activate it in your vscode terminal too, because they are different terminals and u need to activate your venv in all of your terminals. p.n: can you see (venv) in your vscode console? @creative4U

Comment: I use a Docker to run everything so I just use "Compose Up" to run things. 
When I use "dir" is command prompt I do see all the files there though (not sure if that was what you were asking @MojixCoder)

Comment: @MojixCoder I have a different error now, I edited the question with all the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I got the same issue in my windows machine..(probably occurred  because I did some C drive repair)

I also can't able to run `python manage.py runserver` , I got the same error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Django'

I did the following steps.. to overcome my error:

1. On my main folder terminal **Check If you have already a "requiremnts.txt" file skip this step** else run this command: `pip freeze > requirements.txt` ,**if it saves all your packages** **then only do other steps**
2. Delete Venv folder from the main directory.
3. Again install virtual environments and activate Venv.
4. then run this command `pip install -r requirements.txt` this will install all your packages back.
5. Run again `python manage.py runserver` , It will work fine

Comment: So I just tried that, and it still didn't work. It also deleted everything I had in my ```requirements.txt```. I tried putting the libraries back and doing it again. I get other import errors all over the palce

Comment: do you check the path variables?

Comment: It works now thanks. But I can't access the django admin website with the user...

Comment: create a new superuser

Comment: I did, I entered the username email and pw and tried connecting but I get this ```Please enter the correct username and password for a staff account. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive. ``` on the webpage

Comment: in order to access django admin panel..you need to type only username and password..., (email is mandatory while creating a  superuser) also if you create a superuser then it will not be only in staff status.. it will be in superuser status

Comment: I am using the username and pw, (and I checked they are correct normally, since you can't see them when typing in the command prompt)

Comment: may be password error. create another superuser...and TRY again...once if you can able to access the admin panel you can delete others